# Samba guest account not in group?

Tags: samba

I have my samba config as such:

```
[global]
    security = user
    guest account = nobody

[media]
    path = /data/media
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0765
```

Which works fine - windows clients browse to shares as guest and get mapped to the nobody account.  However I have a strange problem.

If I have a file owned by nobody, such as:

```
-rwxrw-r--   1 nobody media   252125 Dec 18  2011 rss.dat
```

My windows clients can do whatever they like to the file.  However if a file is not owned by nobody:

```
-rwxrw-r--   1 user   media   252125 Dec 18  2011 rss.dat
```

Then my windows clients can't touch the file, windows always says you need permission from "SERVER\user" to change the file.  However nobody is in the media group:

```
# From /etc/group
media:x:1002:user,nobody
```

So shouldn't the nobody user be able to change files because of group permissions?  Or is there something special with samba I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be wary of using 'nobody'. This is not its intended use, there are some obscure security concerns with this - much better to add another guest user. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobody_%28username%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a problem because your user does not have media as primary group. Therefore your windows clients try to write the file as **user.user** instead of **user.media**. A simple way of fixing this issue is to **chown** all the files to **nobody.media** inside of **/data/media** you are sharing and forcing clients to write as **nobody.media** . Your smb.conf would look like this

```
[global]
    security = user
    guest account = nobody

[media]
    path = /data/media
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0765
    force user = nobody
    force group = media
```

Comment: That's awesome - the force group option did the trick.  I can now make my files owned by any user and samba users can edit them still because of the group membership.  Thanks!!

Comment: glad I could help